# Android UDP Sample Code Issues

Tags: java, android, udp, eclipse-adt, udpclient

I am currently working on a Android UDP app.  I found some sample code at http://androidituts.com/android-udp-client-server-example/ to achieve my means. However, when I run the code, it crashes at start up. Below is the error from logcat.

[image: Log Cat Error]

Our manifest:

[image]

Our code is directly copied from the website above.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its a `ClassNotFoundException` and in your manifest you have `<activity android:name="com.example.udptest" ...>` which doesnt seem to point to a real class, did you forget the class name after `.udptest` ? (for example `android:name="com.example.udptest.MainActivity"`)